# How do I deal with the POST form

Tags: php, html

I have a `POST` form where of course there is things in it that you need to submit. when I submit it I usually submit them to another file for example `action.php`. Now here is my question: after submitting the file and after all the operations that user wanted are done how do you usually deal with the situation? do you redirect back to the previous page? if so, how can you show that the operation the user wanted are executed and there is no error?
to be more specific look at the following code:

```
if ($_POST['something']) {
$doeverything
if $doeverything 
{
what do you usually put here? how can I show a message here, in the same time, I am back to the previous page where I submitted my information in.
}
```

how can I assign an error after redirecting back?

Comment: Its completely up to you.

Comment: If everything is okay you can redirect back to the previous page. If you need it. If there is an error you can just show it on the same page. If you redirect back to previous page just dont show the error.

Comment: how can I assign an error after redirecting back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the PHP sessions. When you finish your work in `action.php`, you store the message in session like `$_SESSION['message'] = 'Completed'` and you can redirect to previous page. In the page where you have submitted your form, you can show the message using the session like echo `$_SESSION['message']`

Another way may be using `$_GET` super global variable. You can redirect to previous page using `redirect_to('previous_page.php?success=yes').` In previous page you can check the value of `$_GET['success']` and if it is yes you can echo 'Your form is successfully submitted'

Comment: but, in this case, the message will be stored in the session.. and will be viewed every time the user visits the edit page.

Comment: You can make a check_message  function and $message global variable. check_message function checks if the session is set. If it is set then it assigns the session variable to $message and unset the session otherwise it make the $message empty.

Answer (score -1):

You should let the user know whether or not their information was successfully submitted, then direct them to an appropriate page.

For example, if I have a form asking a user to write a short bio about themselves, after they submit it I should:

1. Tell them that their bio has been updated, and
2. Offer them a link to a related page, such as back to their profile page.

Comment: that is exactly my question. so, how do you usually do it?